# convert str type dotted decimal (ip address) to hex in python

Tags: python

I have an ip x.x.x.x assigned to a variable returning as str. Need help in converting this str type ip address to hex

Context:

```
ip = '1.1.1.1'
print type(ip) >>> str

Expected result:
ip = '1.1.1.1'
print ip >>> 0x01010101
```

Please suggest with out having to import ipaddress module. Because we have different server with python versions 2.6 to 3.3. If this script has to run on any server below 3.2, whomsoever running this script had to pip install ipaddress module. Any help is highly appreciated here.

Comment: How about `("0x" + 4 * "{:02x}").format(*[int(i) for i in ip.split('.')])`? Not sure it runs on every Python version. You'd have to check.

Answer (score 1):

```
"0x" + "".join(format(int(octet), "02x") for octet in ip.split("."))
```

Comment: For these simple formats you can use the more efficient `format()` vs `str.format()`, e.g. `format(int(octet), '02x')` instead of `"{:02x}".format(int(octet))`

Comment: I did consider that, but then I figured they were about as clear as one another. I guess that's a smidge better.

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestions.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Please mark the answer as correct if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any extra module to do this, this is a working code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def ip2hex(ip):
    return "0x" + "".join(map(lambda i: "{:02X}".format(int(i)), ip.split(".")))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ip2hex("1.1.1.1"))
    print(ip2hex("192.168.0.2"))
```

will give your desired output:

> 0x01010101
>
> 0xC0A80002

Answer (score 0):

You can have your desired output like this example:

```
def str_to_hex(ip = ''):
    return '0x' + ''.join('{:02x}'.format(int(char)) for char in ip.split('.'))

print(str_to_hex("1.1.1.1"))
print(str_to_hex("213.1.23.1"))
print(str_to_hex("192.168.0.2"))
```

Output:

```
0x01010101
0xd5011701
0xc0a80002
```